# Google Adword API generate refresh token using generate_refresh_token.py

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I follow the step here:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/Using-OAuth-2.0

1. Log in google developers console
2. Create project, then credentials, then acquired the client ID and client secret
3. Install the googleads through pip and download the library: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib
4. Put in client ID and client secret in this example file: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/authentication/generate_refresh_token.py

   CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'

   CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
5. Then I run the generate_refresh_token.py

And I got the following error message:

```
raise AttributeError('No client_id or client_secret specified.')
AttributeError: No client_id or client_secret specified.
```

I'm really new to this and please tell me what I missed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Update May2023`

I am using the below link and the command generates a refresh token for me successfully.

1. You need to download the credentials file from google console first
2. Clone the below repo and go to the path
   https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/examples/authentication/generate_user_credentials.py
3. Run the command

```
python3 generate_user_credentials.py -c <path to credentialsfile>/credentials.json --additional_scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you generate a new client secret. It worked for me.

Comment: How did you created a new client secret?